# Do I really need all the vendor components for using the google calendar api?

Tags: php, api, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to use the Google Calendar API. I'm not using Composer to install it. I downloaded the https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client and it says to download a release version if you're not using composer.

Okay easy enough. However, the release version comes with a vendor folder and it contains thousands of files. It takes forever to upload and I'm shipping it to clients as part of another application. Do I really need all of these just to use a simple Google Calendar API?

Comment: All of them? Probably not. Do you want to go through it removing files and testing everything still works? I wouldn't. You could always zip (or other compression) up the entire project, then it's only one file to deploy.

Comment: Haha, I just asked myself this two days ago while waiting to upload 48 zillion files just to authenticate a user through Google. If it's just the uploading that's an issue, I'm with @Jonnix: can you zip it for upload and have something unzip it on the other end?

Comment: 1. Use composer. 2. Are your clients on 1990s servers where 8MB of code/assets is a problem?

Comment: @ceejayoz, for me, it wasn't the total size that was the issue, but the thousands of files that made this take forever for me. I could upload an 8MB zip in less than a second from here, but all these files took a really long time

Comment: @Stevish If you were using Composer, as any PHP developer really should be in 2019, that wouldn't be an issue. If the host doesn't support it, it's time to ditch them.